# Changing the default color of the button when the mouse hovers over it

Tags: c#, wpf, button, colors

I am just learning C# programming language and I am interested in learning the VPF development framework. My question is, how can I change the default color of this button when the mouse hovers over it?
I hope you understand my question

[This is the default color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtxyE.png)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Button Width="120" Height="60" Background="Blue" >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            clic me
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I use Visual Studio, could it be because of this?
I have tried various sources, especially the sources of artificial orgasm, but none of them helped me
I just want to change this stupid pale blue default color